# How to output all attributes jbuilder, without having to specify them all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using json to store document versions of my data in postgresql.  I would like to output an entire tree of objects with children, children of children etc and all attributes.  If any attributes are added to any of the objects at a later date, I would like them to be include in subsequent json.

Is there any way to output the entire contents without having to least each and every attribute? ie not like this:

```
json.(object_name, :id, :attr1, :attr2.... etc)
```

Comment: Note: the [tag:jbuilder] tag’s description is wrong in this case. This question is about the [Jbuilder JSON DSL for Ruby](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder), not the [JBuilder Java IDE](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/jbuilder).

Comment: “Output the entire contents” of what? What kind of object do you have that already contains a list of attributes? Is it a [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html)?

Comment: I don't think there is. The whole idea behind JSON templates is that you get control over the what's exposed and what's not. Why don't you use `to_json`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, no way to do this.  Ended listing everything.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane if you used `Hash` then just use `Hash` variable name `json.merge! HASH`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but I was wondering the same thing, and ended up here. Then I found a great answer here => [How to extract all attributes with Rails Jbuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027644/how-to-extract-all-attributes-with-rails-jbuilder/23422260#23422260)

@uiureo suggests to use `json.merge!`, and that worked perfactly for me :)

```
json.merge! object_name.attributes
```

Comment: To anyone, remember to upgrade Jbuilder if you get "merge!" as json node.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your json to ouput like this:

```
{"id":1,"attribute1":1,"attribute2":2}
```

You can do this:

```
json.array! @my_object
```

However, if you want output that looks likes this:

```
{"my_object":{"id":1,"attribute1":1,"attribute2":2}}
```

You can do this:

```
json.my_object @my_object
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the ! does?

Comment: @Chris In Ruby, `.array!` is just a call to a method with the name `array!`, which is a different method from `array`. By convention, methods with names ending in `!` mutate the object, or are more permanent or dangerous. I am guessing that in this case, it indicates mutation of `json`. You would have to look up the documentation for the `#array!` method to see exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at `json.except!`

`json.except! @resource, :id, :updated_at`

`json.except! @resource`

https://github.com/chenqingspring/jbuilder-except