# How to extract all attributes with Rails Jbuilder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

It's a pain to write codes like this all the time in jbuilder.json template:

```
json.extract! notification, :id, :user_id, :notice_type, :message, :resource_type, :resource_id, :unread, :created_at, :updated_at
```

So I'd like to code like this;

```
json.extract_all! notification
```

I've found I can do it like the following codes, but they are still a bit lengthy to me.

```
notification.attributes.each do |key, value|
  json.set!(key, value)
end
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Maybe this is a bit simpler, `json.extract! notification, *notification.attributes.keys` But if Jbuilder has a method like this, I want to use it instead.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Maybe you can use `json.merge!`.

```
json.merge! notification.attributes
```

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/master/lib/jbuilder.rb#L277

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want!! Only, my Rails version is 4.0 so I should upgrade it to 4.1 first.

Comment: I just tried to use this method with Rails 4.1 but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be merged into 4.1. So I decided to wait a little more.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jbuilder? Try `bundle update jbuilder`.

Comment: Oh jbuilder is only a gem and has nothing to do with Rails versions as of now. The method worked fine with jbuilder 2.1.1! Thank you for your trouble.

Comment: Beware revealing sensitive attributes. Add a `reject` to filter one or more out: `json.merge! user.attributes.reject {|k, v| k == 'encrypted_password' }`

Comment: Works great in jbuild 2.11, Rails 7rc

Answer (score 11):

I'm using jbuilder 1.5.0 and merge! didn't work but I found an alternative syntax:

```
json.(notification, *notification.attributes.keys)
```

Comment: As @Dakuan said, this obeys `JBuilder.key_format` setting, which is necessary if you're converting your keys from snake_case to camelCase. According to [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?language=en&view=asciicast) I believe this syntax won't work in some versions of ruby, in which case the working syntax is `json.extract! notification, *notification.attributes.keys`

Answer (score 3):

Adding more to @uiureo 's  answer

Suppose your Notification has some type of image uploaders (e.g. carrierwave,paperclip)

**Then below version will not return you uploader object, so how do you get the image url?**

```
json.merge! notification.attributes
```

`notification.attributes` is hash conversion of object, it will return mounted uploader column value but not the url.

### sample response

```
notification: Object {
   title: "hellow world"
   img: "sample.png"
}
```

Instead try this

```
json.merge! notification.as_json
```

**This will return mounted column as another object in which you can query for url.**

### sample response

```
notification: Object {
   title: "hellow world"
   img: Object {
       url: "https://www.example.com/sample.png"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may look at `json.except!`

`json.except! @resource, :id, :updated_at`

`json.except! @resource`

https://github.com/chenqingspring/jbuilder-except

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to exclude any of the attributes. Ex: `created_at` and `updated_at`

```
json.merge! notification.attributes.reject{ |key, _| key.in?(['created_at', 'updated_at']) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it

```
json.property  do
  Property.column_names.each do |name|
     json.set! name, @property.try(name)
  end

  # has_ones:
  json.contact @property.contact
end
```

It's easy to see what's happening, add logic to omit fields etc doing it this way.