# Jbuilder include All Attributes and Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm trying to set up a JSON object that I can make a clone of, so I need Jbuilder to list all object attributes and associations. I've done plenty of pick and choose JSON structures using Jbuilder, but can't seem to find a simple way to just list everything in one swoop without explicitly declaring it all.

This works fine for individual `company` attributes and all associated `location` attributes...

```
//show.json.jbuilder

company = @company

json.company do
  json.(company, :id)
  json.locations_attributes company.locations
end
```

But I'd like to include ALL the `company` attributes and can't seem to do it without listing them all `json.(company, :id, :name, :line_of_business)` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use `ActiveRecord` [#attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes) method to look neat as

```
company = @company

json.company do
  json.(company, *company.attributes.keys)
  json.locations_attributes company.locations
end
```

Or as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23422260/6548745) answer:

```
json.merge! company.attributes
```